# invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')

Tags: c, int, double

This is not my entire code, but I keep getting this error : *invalid operands to binary expression*.

```
printf("How much change is owed?\n");
float change= GetFloat();
float roundf(float change);
change*=100;
int rem;

while (change>0)

{
    if(change>=0.25)
    rem=change % 0.25;      > error, saying that this is a double???? 
}
printf ("%d\n", rem);          I need the modulo , it is not working
return 0;
```

Comment: Use fmod(a, b) instead.

Comment: After multiplying by 100, and rounding, you should be able to write the rest of the program using integer math and integer variables.

Comment: Hmmm, if `change > 0.0` then `while (change>0)

{
    if(change>=0.25)
    rem=whatever; 
}` looks like an infinite loop.

Comment: Don't use floating point if you need **exact** arithmetic results.

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++ the operator `%` is not defined for floating numbers. It is defined only for integer types.

So the compiler issues an error because in this expression

```
rem=change % 0.25;
```

the both operands are floating numbers. Here `0.25` is a floating literal of type `double` and the variable `change` is declared as having type `float`.

```
float change= GetFloat();
```

Use `fmod` or `remainder` functions from `<math.h>`.